# Pass in ApplicationUser GUID Id from action link to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I am using Identity AspNetUser tables. I have a different controller for user profile as it has too many attributes. After user logs in, I would like to show a link to "Edit Profile". I want the GUID id from AspNetUser tables to be passed to my site Customer Profile controller.

I have added a link in _Layout.cshtml

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
          <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
  @Html.ActionLink("User Profile", "Index", "CustomerProfile", new { id = User.Identity.})</li>
                }



   Controller Code: 
   public ActionResult Index(string UserID)
    {
        //Show Customer User Profile with details
        return View();
    }
```

I would like UserID in controller to have ID of logged In user. Also, I would like the details of that user to be shown on profile page.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the identity information to the controller action?  Can't the controller action determine the current logged-in user just as the view does?

Comment: And whats the problem?

Comment: @David: Are you saying to not pass in the parameter string UserID in the index function, but get the current user in the index function?

Comment: @Gauravsa I am trying to pass in UserId in the index function so I can change the profile of that particular user. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: @LearnAspNet: Exactly.  I mean, obviously you'd want to *validate* that they're editing themselves and not someone else, right?  The same logic which would validate it would just identify them in the first place.